# User to create a custom folder and for it to go into a dropdown list for them only

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I have a website and I have a form which enables the user to add in some information. I want to create a dropdown which will allow them to put their form entry into a folder. I know how to create a options for them to add to default folders. But, how can I allow them to create a new folder which will then go into that dropdown list which they can then choose again if needed? Can this be achieved through Javascript?

Comment: Client-side JavaScript can not create a folder on the server, at most it can trigger a request (AJAX) to a server-side script that then creates the folder there.

Comment: But you could also create the folder only when the form gets submitted. Make one of your dropdown options "Create new folder", and when that one gets selected, you show an additional text field (via JavaScript), where the user can enter the desired new folder name. And on the server side, when you process the form submission, you first create that folder, if any value was submitted via this text field.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe. Basically, the user clicks add new button and then a pop up form appears, they can then put in their inputs and there is a dropdown which shows folder, at the moment beneath that folder dropdown is a button which says add new folder, if they type in that, how do I then get it to into the dropdown and for it to remember it for the future? Also, how can i set this to be just for the user and no one else?

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense to try and put it into the select field at the point when the user is creating the folder. They just typed the new folder name into a text field - so leave it there, and _take_ it from there, on the server side? _"and for it to remember it for the future?"_ - aren't you building that list dynamically yet, by reading the existing folders from the server? Then you should perhaps implement that now.

Comment: _"Also, how can i set this to be just for the user and no one else?"_ - that is a very broad question at this point, we don't know any details about how your system works. Are you creating those folders inside a user-specific folder, do you have "their" folders stored in a database, ...?